# HtmlGenericControl list keeps returning null

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, htmlgenericcontrol

I have a function that loads a list of contacts and puts a checkbox next to each contact. Any contact that gets tick then gets an email sent to them. But in my email function the list is always coming back as zero.

Code for list:

```
   <div id="viewMenuDropFollowup" style="top:0px;right:10px; text-align: left; display:none">
                    <strong>Email to</strong> <a onclick="OpenEmail()" style="float:right;font-weight:bold;cursor:pointer">X</a>
                    <ul runat="server" id="ulCRMContacts">

                    </ul>
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtEmailTo" ></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="btnEmail3" CssClass="btnEmail" OnClick="btnEmail_Click" Text="Email" ToolTip="Email to selected contacts" OnClientClick="return CheckEmail()"></asp:LinkButton>
                </div>
                <a id="btnOpenEmail" onclick="OpenEmail()" class="EmailClass"><strong>Email</strong></a>

function OpenEmail() {
        if (document.getElementById("viewMenuDropFollowup").style.display === "block") {
            document.getElementById("viewMenuDropFollowup").style.display = "none";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("viewMenuDropFollowup").style.display = "block";
        }
    }
```

Code to load contacts:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)    
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        LoadContacts();
     }    
}

     protected void LoadContacts()
        {
            Customer c = new Customer(int.Parse(CustomerID));

            foreach (Customer.CustomerContact cc in c.Contacts)
            {
                HtmlGenericControl li = new HtmlGenericControl("li");
                CheckBox cb = new CheckBox();
                cb.ID = "cbCRMContact_" + cc.ID;
                cb.Checked = true;
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cc.Email))
                {
                    cb.Text = cc.Email;
                    cb.TextAlign = TextAlign.Right;
                    li.Controls.Add(cb);
                    ulCRMContacts.Controls.Add(li);
                }
            }

            GetControls(ulCRMContacts.Controls);
        }
```

I put the line `GetControls(ulCRMContacts.Controls);` to see if I can get the controls and it works fine here. But when I try call `GetControls(ulCRMContacts.Controls);` again in my email function it returns zero.

```
  protected void btnEmail_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (EmailFollowup(new lookupCRMCustomerContact(Company.Current.CompanyID, int.Parse(Request.QueryString["CustID"]))))
            {
                DisplayMsg("Follow up has been emailed");
            }
            else
            {
                DisplayMsg("An Error Occurred sending email. Please contact Support");
            }
        }

public bool EmailFollowup(lookupCRMCustomerContact q)
{
      GetControls(ulCRMContacts.Controls);
}
```

It's like it loses the values in `ulCRMContacts` as soon as it leave the `LoadContacts` function.

Comment: When are you running `EmailFollowup` and when `LoadContacts`?

Comment: @Andrei `LoadContacts` runs as soon as the page loads. `EmailFollowup` doesn't run until an email button is clicked

Comment: If you have AutoPostBack="true" on the buttons, then there's your problem. You need to put in the condition if (!IsPostBack){..} in your LoadContacts() function.

Comment: @Kami, isn't it the other way? These controls are added dynamically, so OP has to make sure they are actually added on each postback. I was about to ask if they have this condition anywhere perchance

Comment: Can you please post event handlers code that calls these methods? These are important details.

Comment: @Andrei I updated the question with the code

Comment: Btw, you never use the argument `lookupCRMCustomerContact` in `EmailFollowup`. You should call `LoadContacts` from `Page_Init` always, so on every postback too.

Comment: Whatever calls `LoadContacts` is still missing

Comment: @Andrei sorry, added that code now

Comment: @TimSchmelter I'm calling `LoadContacts` from `Page_Load`

Comment: @user123456789: i know, that's why i've suggested to use `Page_Init`. But important is that you call it on every postback too, not only once.

Comment: Yep, exactly as I suspected, that was the most important piece. As Tim already suggested multiple times, you should be calling LoadContacts on every postback. Remove your `if` condition in Page_Load, and that should do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to (re-)create dynamic controls on every postback too, so this won't work:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)    
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        LoadContacts();
     }    
}
```

Remove the `!IsPostBack`-check and it should work. If you still have issues move it to `Page_Init` which is the appropriate event.

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)    
{
    LoadContacts();   
}
```